# C++ power consumption cant be calculated

Tags: c++

So I am very new to `C++` but trying to learn. I have been trying to deal with this problem for over 5 hours and cant seem to fix my issue.
At line 24:

> float Pris=kWh*elpris; // total pris

I get this error:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('float (*)(float, float)' and 'float')

I am trying to multiply kWh with pris (price) so get a kWh price...
What am i missing or doing wrong?
Thank you in advance

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Edit here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


float kWh(float Watt, float Tid) {
    return Watt / 1000 * Tid;

}
int main() {

    float elpris; //elpris pr Kwh
    float Watt; //Watt enheden bruger
    float Tid; //Antal timer enheden bliver brugt
    float pris;
    
    //------*Here Error occurred*-------------------- 
    float Pris=kWh*elpris; // total pris
    
    cout << "Skriv din endheds Watt ";
    cin >> Watt;
    
    cout << "skriv din forbrugstid i timer ";
    cin >> Tid;
    
    cout << "skriv din elpris pr kWh i dkk: ";
    cin >> elpris;
    
    cout << "Forbruget er " <<kWh(Watt, Tid); cout << "kWh" <<endl;
    cout << "din pris er: " <<Pris;
}
```

Comment: The Danish is wonderful. What is not so good is the lack of code inline in the question. Links break and folk don't follow them. If you want your question answered, please edit. Cheers,.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean lack of code? should i post the code istead of an image?

Comment: Exactly. Please put the code inline.

Comment: Okay i will try to do that - sorry

Comment: It turned out kinda weird - maybe i did something wrong?

Comment: You can't calculate values before they have been initialized. A `c++` assignment is evaluated 1 time at the line it appears in the code. It's not a mathematical relationship that gets evaluated in the future. Also the function call for kWh misses its parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here

```
float Pris=kWh*elpris;
```

`kWh` is a *function* and requires two parameters, as you do further down the program.

The fix is to remove that statement. Towards the end of the program write instead

```
float kwh = kWh(Watt, Tid);
cout << "Forbruget er " <<hwh;
cout << "kWh" <<endl;
float Pris=kwh*elpris; 
cout << "din pris er: " <<Pris;
```

Comment: Ah so basically it just had to be arranged diffrently?

Comment: Now i am getting this error in the first line you fixed for me :O

Comment: Called object type 'float' is not a function or function pointer

Comment: @HGPlays `kwh` versus `kWh` perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

Change this line:

from

```
float kWh = kWh(Watt, Tid);
```

to

```
float reskWh = kWh(Watt, Tid);
```

from

```
float pris = kWh * elpris;
```

to

```
float pris = reskWh * elpris;
```

Comment: Thank you but @Bathsheba has helped me with my project :)